# Where could I check to remove temp stored personal files

Tags: macos, finder, high-sierra, filesystem, file

Do Mac's save any cached versions of files so that if using someone else's laptop or borrowing own laptop to a relative for temp usage need to be aware to remove to avoid personal info being seen?
E.g. I recently noticed the `Recents` in the `Finder` so I was wondering if there is anything else

Comment: The way it is currently phrased, the question is too broad. If you are concerned about leaving traces of data while borrowing someone else's Mac, it's best to use it by logging into Guest user account. Guest user account removes all traces of activity/data upon logging out.

Comment: this utility will delete *all* the temp files on your Mac. https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html

Comment: Yes, in the root of the e.g Macintosh HD there. Is a hidden directory called `.DocumentRevisions-V100` that could possibly contain information you'd not want anyone else having access to.

Comment: @user3439894:I found it. What is stored there?  Is it safe to do an `rm -rf .DocumentRevisions-V100`?

Comment: In short, it stores version copies of things you've worked on and made changes to. If you search the Internet for [macos document versions](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=5LGSXLn_KcfUjwT6-qqYCw&q=macos+document+versions&btnK=Google+Search&oq=macos+document+versions&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30l2.2424.8101..10580...0.0..0.163.3420.0j23......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0i131j0j0i22i10i30.Qlm_72_vMA0) you'll see a bit more what its about.

Comment: Also have a look at my answer: [A: What will occur if the .DocumentRevisions-V100 folder is deleted?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313102/what-will-occur-if-the-documentrevisions-v100-folder-is-deleted/313112#313112)