# TextEdit not closing without asking me for a file name

Tags: macos, textedit

Previously, macOS using TextEdit and other apps allow blank documents to be edited and closing them without having to save the files, even for new files that were not giving a name yet.

I have to reinstall Catalina recently, and now, every time I close TextEdit it asks me to save or delete the file.

It appears TextEdit is not working normally anymore and there is no preference to adjust that.

This does not do the trick

```
defaults write com.apple.TextEdit ApplePersistence -bool yes
```

Any way to solve that?

Comment: Does it ask you to save or delete even when you've saved it?

Comment: yes, but if I am not wrong, it would save the file state automatically, even for not previously saved files.

Comment: For files that you've opened and edited without saving, you can close the window and the document is saved automatically. Is that what you're experiencing?

Comment: For new files it makes total sense not to autosave them because you haven't given them a name and location on the disk yet.

Comment: Spacedog is referring to the document version history framework where all new empty documents get full save / version / undo before saving to the user visible part of the filesystem. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313102/what-will-occur-if-the-documentrevisions-v100-folder-is-deleted

Comment: yes, when I try to close TextEdit it asks me to save or delete. I want TextEdit to close and save the file automatically, the magic it always did.

Comment: I have reinstalled Catalina yesterday. This should not be the normal behavior.

Comment: Try the command `defaults read com.apple.TextEdit` in terminal. Does it have the key `ApplePersistenceIgnoreState`, and is it set to true or false?

Comment: Thanks guys, I found the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the culprit. This box was turned on.

[image]